# EJB lookup from PostConstruct method in GlassFish 3.1.2

Tags: glassfish, ejb, glassfish-3, lookup, postconstruct

Deploying ear on Glassfish 3.1.2 and trying to lookup EJB bean from @PostConstruct method in web service:

```
   @PostConstruct
   public void init()
   {
      try
      {
         InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();

         browserService = (IBrowserService) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/BrowserService");
      }
      catch (NamingException ex)
      {
         Logger.getLogger(BrowserWS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }

   }
```

and got

[#|2012-04-25T10:15:54.768+0300|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|browser.service.BrowserWS|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4
);|javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/BrowserService' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterpri
se.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.ur
l.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Invocation exception: Got null ComponentInvocation ]
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)

When i try do the same from web method all works fine.

```
@WebMethod
   public XmlLookupResult lookup(
      @WebParam(name = "inLookupId", mode = WebParam.Mode.IN) String id,
      @WebParam(name = "inLookupParams", mode = WebParam.Mode.IN) List<String> params,
      @WebParam(name = "inFetchLimit", mode = WebParam.Mode.IN) int limit)
   {

      try
      {
         InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();

         browserService = (IBrowserService) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/BrowserService");
      }
      catch (NamingException ex)
      {
         Logger.getLogger(BrowserWS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }

      return browserService.lookup(id, params, limit);
   }
```

So, why i can't lookup beans from @PostConstruct method?

From specification whe have JNDI access to java:comp/env from PostConstruct...

Thanks

UPD:

BrowserService declared in web.xml as

```
<ejb-local-ref>
   <ejb-ref-name>BrowserService</ejb-ref-name>
   <local>browser.service.IBrowserService</local>
</ejb-local-ref>
```

Comment: Where and how did you declare that BrowserService is in the ENC of BrowserWS? What happens if you use injection instead?

Comment: BrowserService declared in web.xml as 
<ejb-local-ref>
   <ejb-ref-name>BrowserService</ejb-ref-name>
   <local>com.softcomputer.csf.browser.service.IBrowserService</local>
</ejb-local-ref>

For some reason i can't use injection.

Comment: Of course you can use injection ;) Start with a minimal example, try to avoid doing 'weird things', ie don't use strange jars that you don't need, don't use XML at all. Use  two simple beans only, inject one in the other. If it doesn't work, create a new question for this. Moral of story: get the basics right first! "can't inject" sounds like you have other problems elsewhere.

Comment: It is not a tutorial example. It is real project and we need to support jboss 4.x that don't allow bean injection to web service.

Comment: Right... JBoss 4.x? Isn't that a bit new still? Anyway, I understand your issue now.